# Linear Algebra, Polynomial transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

```
T:p^3->p^2
T(p(x)) = 3p'(x)+p(0)(x^2-5)
```

The first step to this is to transform T(7-2x+4x^3)
which comes out for me to be 43x^2-41

The next part is to find [T]bb' and multiply it with t(7-2x+4x^3) to confirm that [T]bb'
is in fact correct. This the part that I can't figure out.

I think i have to construct a matrix using B={1,x,x^2,x^3} and B'={1,x,x^2}
I'm getting:

```
T(1)=x^2-5
T(x)=3
T(x^2)=6x
T(x^3)=9x^2
```

constructing the matrix as:

```
<0 0 0 1>
<0 6 0 0>   
<9 0 3 -5>
```

and multiplying it to

```
<7 -2 0 4>
```

but now matter what i do i do not get 43x^2-41
Please help, this is driving me crazy as i can't seem to find the answer anywhere
in my text book or online. Also, I'm not entirely sure what the B'={1,x,x^2}
is used for. Am I supposed to construct a second matrix and multiply it with the first to
find [T]bb'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is incorrect, the columns should be the coordinate vectors with respect to the basis $B^{\prime}$ of the transformation $T$ applied to each basis element of $B$. So if you define

$$[T]_{B^{\prime}\leftarrow B} = \begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 3 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 &6 &0\\
1 & 0 & 0 &9
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 3 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 &6 &0\\
1 & 0 & 0 &9
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
7\\
-2\\
0\\
4
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-41\\
0\\
43
\end{bmatrix}$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was doubting the construction of [T]bb', its a relief to know that it was the order that was wrong.